# why a class name is given before a code block in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, codeblocks

I am new to scala, went through some tutorials and in one sample i came across

```
object DataController extends SomeOtherController with Controller {
...
    def testPage = SomeOtherAction { implicit requestHolder =>
        val userInfo = requestHolder.user 
        val paramMap = requestHolder.params
        .....
    }
}
```

here = sign means the following code block is assigned to a function called testPage.
But why is a class name "SomeOtherAction" is given before the code block?
Need some pointers regarding the same.

Answer (score 8):

The `SomeOtherAction` is actually an object, not a class, and must have an apply method. This "code block" is not simply a block, it's a function that takes the type of requestHolder. So, `SomeOtherAction` could be like that

```
object SomeOtherAction {
  //...
  def apply(r:RequestHolder => Unit) = {
    // do something
    r(someRequestHolder) 
  }
}
```

When Scala sees an argument being applied to an object it seeks for the method apply.

The use of `Unit` above is only a illustration of one possible scenario.

The final piece of the puzzle is that for any method, including `apply`, the argument expressions can be either bounded by parentheses, or (if there's only 1) can be a single block expression, i.e. bounded by braces `{}`. This is detailed in section 6.6 of the Language Specification for function application syntax:

```
SimpleExpr ::= SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs
ArgumentExprs ::= ‘(’ [Exprs] ‘)’
| ‘(’ [Exprs ‘,’] PostfixExpr ‘:’ ‘_’ ‘*’ ’)’
| [nl] BlockExpr
Exprs ::= Expr {‘,’ Expr}
```

e.g. `def foo(x: Int) = x * 100` can be called via `foo(42)` or  `foo {println("yo"); 42}`

Comment: @luigi plinge, I thought about mentioning it. But felt a little beyond the scope of the question. Now reading it again it is indeed a missing link. Thanks.